# Is this an architecture limitation of no-www? :

Tags: php, asp.net, perl, jsp, web

If I belong to the [no-www camp](http://no-www.org/), cookies I have set in `http://example.com` would be read by `http://sub-domain.example.com`,

And regardless of the language I use (perl / asp.net / php / JSP) there is **no way** I could ever work around this issue because it is a fundamental architecture of HTTP itself, **true** or **false** ?

What I'm concerned here is, is there any DNS config that would prevent `http://sub-domain.example.com` from reading the cookies set in `http://example.com` ?

I have a domain name http://qweop.com

I have a subdomain at http://sd.qweop.com

> Now, the problem is that even though I've not set any cookies on `http://sd.qweop.com`, when I read the cookies, there are cookies there. They are reading cookies from `http://qweop.com`.

How do I fix the problem so that the cookies from the main domain would not be read by (a request to) the sub-domain?

I've tried altering the 5th parameter of the [php setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) function but it doesn't seem to do anything. Basically that parameter is like useless. I'm suspecting it's a limitation of the HTTP infrastructure.

**DETAILS:**

http://qweop.com/set.php (try to use incognito to allow easy cookie removal)

```
<?php setcookie("testcookie","testvalue",time()+60*60*24*30,"/","qweop.com");?>
cookies set
```

http://sd.qweop.com/read.php

```
<?php print_r($_COOKIE); ?>
// No one had set any cookies in http://sd.qweop.com but we can see cookies here! Error!
```

**Answer: Yes**

I had better catalog the answer here after 500 hours of google research.

Basically we should always use www if we're planning to use any other sub-domains and we want them cookie-free. This is because there are different **browser behaviors** with regards to top-level domain cookies.

We can try our best to tell the browser "Hey's set it to just the domain and not to it's sub-domains" but as long as the url is non-www, they won't be nice and behave the way we want them to.

In fact, even if the url is not non-www, they can still do *whatever* they want to, there is currently no record of any browser that does that (and most likely so too into the future).

Comment: when you set a cookie with php you have the option of setting the domain scope. http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: @Dagon I've tried that but it isn't working, not unless the domain also matched the domain of the page itself. it seems like a bogus feature to me.

Comment: post your php, as i have no issues settings cookies by domain

Comment: http://sd.qweop.com/read.php = Array(), sure you don't have some legacy cookies, have you removed all from browser before loading the page.

Comment: If you are testing, test it with: `time()+5` to refresh the cookies

Comment: @Dagon the "set.php" should set the cookies to `qweop.com` (since that's what the qweop.com site does, setting cookies to qweop.com) and not `sd.qweop.com`.. edited. test it again, the cookies are showing up for my case. no legacy cookies, I'm testing in incognito.

Comment: May I ask, why it's a very important question to you? May be things aren't that bad as you imagine?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel it is important to me because I value correct knowledge  more highly than "rumor knowledge"

Comment: ah. you completely misled your question then. you have to read interned standards, not asking questions on the site which, in fact, being source of these rumors.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel what I've learned from the site in fact, is that internet standards are usually not implemented correctly, so they are useful, but not sufficient for practical uses.

Comment: exactly. a practical case - that's what I've been asking from you for the whole day :)

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel That's what I've have had provided. I have no interested in internet standards. I was only kindly pointing out that they can be useful but are in fact **useless** for practical uses when you told me to read the internet standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you cannot do anything about it. You might try to set the cookie as:

```
setcookie('some_name', 'some_val', 0, '/', 'yourdomain');
```

but it will be set to all subdomains of `yourdomain` even though [RFC 2109](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2109.html) says if the cookie is to match the subdomains it should be set with a dot as `.yourdomain`. All major browsers are sending it to the subdomains. I checked it with IE, FF and Chrome.

Comment: hmm, anyway to hack around it? is this a PHP only problem or is it that no matter what language I use (perl etc) there's still no way around it? (btw for my case the path must be `/`  because the cookies are required to be set to `http://qweop.com` and not `http://qweop.com/some-folder`)

Comment: The path doesn't matter in this case. It is definitely not PHP related. PHP will send its session cookies the proper way: `Set-Cookie PHPSESSID=dsle71ekd90pu9ngmdonmq0ee3; path=/; domain=.yourdomain` As you can see with the dot. The problem is that the browsers don't follow the specifications and will regard `domain=yourdomain` as `domain=.yourdomain` I cannot think of a way around this but to go with yes-www.org

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, DNS config has absolutely nothing to do with cookies (as long as they belong to the same 2-nd level domain, of course).

You still can have a practical answer if you ask a practical question though.

Comment: I have asked a practical question.

Comment: no, according to your own comment, you were looking for pure theoretical knowledge, not solving whatever practical problem

Comment: I wasn't. I have a practical problem that needs solving and I'm looking for pure practical knowledge. Look at the edited post.